# How to implement application insight sampling at function level in azure function

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have a azure function app in .net core 6, which contains 3 (just for example) different EventHub trigger functions, one of those function is producing too many logs in application insight, so I want to implement application insight sampling at function level so that I can sample only logs for that specific function, I don't want to lose any logs for other 2 functions,

Suppose these are functions I have,
Function1
Function2
Function3

Function2 produces thousands logs while Function1 and Function3 produces only few logs, if I apply sampling at function app level then I will lose the logs from Function1 and Function3 as well, which I don't want to lose, I don't care about Function2 logs.

So how I can implement custom application insight sampling so that it will sample logs of Function2 only, and rest of the functions will logs everything in app insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an Event Hub Namespace and added three event hubs.

[image]

- I created a function app in Visual Studio, and I have added three event hub trigger functions.
- I have implemented sampling custom telemetry to function2 to control some logs in application insights.

**CustomTelemetryProcessor.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;

public class CustomTelemetryProcessor : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private readonly ITelemetryProcessor _next;
    private readonly string _functionName;

    public CustomTelemetryProcessor(ITelemetryProcessor next, string functionName)
    {
        _next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
        _functionName = functionName ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(functionName));
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));
        }

       
        if (item.Context.Operation.Name == _functionName)
        {
            if (ShouldSample())
            {
                _next.Process(item);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            
            _next.Process(item);
        }
    }

    private bool ShouldSample()
    {
       
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FunctionApp800.Startup))]

namespace FunctionApp800
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

           
            var telemetryConfiguration = TelemetryConfiguration.Active;
            telemetryConfiguration.DefaultTelemetrySink.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder
                .Use((next) => new CustomTelemetryProcessor(next, "Function2"));

           
        }
    }
}
```

**Function2:**

```
 public static class Function2
 {
     private static readonly TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();

     [FunctionName("Function2")]
     public static async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("event2", Connection = "EventHubConnectionFunction2")] EventData[] events, ILogger log)
     {
         var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

         foreach (EventData eventData in events)
         {
             var telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
             telemetry.TrackTrace("Function2 processing message: " + eventData);

            
         }
     }

 }
```

**local.setting.json:**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "EventHubConnectionFunction1": "connection string of event1",
    "EventHubConnectionFunction2": "connection string of event2",
    "EventHubConnectionFunction3": "connection string of event3",
    "Function2SamplingPercentage": "10",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "your instrumentation key"
  }
}
```

The above code is working fine and The Three Event Hub Trigger functions triggered successfully. I am able control some logs in application insights.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks, this issue was resolved already, but solution is same as you provided, so I will accept it.